Why Consider Only Triplet States for Spin in $2$-Electron Systems?
I have a question regarding systems of 2 electrons and their spin properties. When the Hamiltonian of a system of 2 electrons can be written as a sum of two single-particle Hamiltonians that are identical, I am told that in order to find stationary states I need to find eigenstates that are also either the singlet or triplet for the spin.
The part I don't understand is this: triplet eigenstates are symmetric, but they are not the only possible symmetric states. For example, combining two triplet states still yields a symmetric state. Since spin does not appear in the Hamiltonian, why do I necessarily need to consider only triplet states and not some other symmetric states?

Doesn't triplet in this context just mean $S_{tot} = 1$?

yes, but why stationary states should have $S_{tot}=0$? if the spin is not in the hamiltonian

You can consider any states, but if you're after a basis, some states are more important (part of the basis). Do you know the concept of complete set of commuting operators?

Yes, I understand the concept, but I don't see why the electron can't be stationary and symmetric without being in a triplet state. Indeed the triplet states are a complete set of all the symmetric states.
If the spin were included in the Hamiltonian, then I would understand why only triplet.

Maybe you just misunderstood or somebody told you wrong. When we're after a basis, we have the four orthogonal states, three triplet states, and one single state. In magnetic field, they are the Hamiltonian eigenstates, with different energies, differences of which show up as peaks in spectra. When we're after any stationary state in absence of magnetic field, then we can make any linear combination of states with the same energy. So indeed, any linear combination of triplet states should be a stationary state (assuming such simple Hamiltonian with no spins and no external magnetic field).

But if the pair is in magnetic field, degeneracy gets removed, and only these different basis states, not their arbitrary linear combinations, are Hamiltonian eigenstates.

This is slightly strange.  In any case what matters is that the fermionic states should be fully antisymmetric w/r to permutations of the particles, and that means spin and spatial degrees of freedom.  Combining two spins can only result in an antisymmetric spin singlet or a symmetric spin triplet
Many types of (attractive) interactions produce ground states that are symmetric under permutations of the positions of particles.  This immediately implies the spin part must be antisymmetric ($S=0$, or singlet).  On the other hand, it may well be that the state you are interested is spatially antisymmetric in which case the spin part will be symmetric: any one of the $S=1$ states, or any linear combination of them unless the Hamiltonian depends on spins.
It is true that products of two symmetric states is also symmetric, but then you would be describing a system with 4 not 2 spins.  For instance, the state $\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle$ can be combined with another $\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle$ but that makes $\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle$ which is a 4-spin state (with $S=2$ so part of a quintet).

Spin is inherent in the 4-component Dirac equation, but even here direct computation of the 2-particle wavefunction $\Psi(r_1, r_2) = \Psi(r_2, r_1)$ is still not antisymmetric (because the Hamiltonian is symmetric under exchange of indices). Without apriori endowing "antisymmetry-ness" in the analytic form of the 2 electron wavefunction, could we show by direct calculation that the 2-particle wavefunction $\Psi(r_1, r_2) = -\Psi(r_2, r_1)$ is demonstrably antisymmetric in the Dirac equation?

@James I would not know how to do this.

Thank you, I am not really familiar with the historical development of QM, was the antisymmetric construction of the 2-body wavefunction $\Psi(x_{1},x_{2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\Psi_{1}(x_{1})\Psi_{2}(x_{2})-\Psi_{1}(x_{2})\Psi_{2}(x_{1})\right]\tag{2}$ taken as an additional postulate not derivable by anything priorly doable by the QM machinery?

More generally, since behavior of entanglement seems contained within the 2-body wavefunction $\Psi(x_1, x_2)$, how could we really study entanglement behavior if our construction of the 2-body wavefunction is ad-hoc to begin with?

@James correct.  Within non-relativistic QM the symmetrization postulate an additional postulate.

@James yes, at first people tried to use just products of one-electron eigenfunctions (Hartree), but such psi function did not manifest anything like the Pauli exclusion principle. Then in few years, Slater and Fock, independently, used antisymmetric function (Slater determinant), which obeys the principle.

@JánLalinský thank you. I have been looking at a numerical solution to the 2-electron wavefunction of helium with $H = - \nabla^2_1 -\nabla^2_2 - \frac{1}{r_1} - \frac{1}{r_2} + \frac{1}{|r_1-r_2|}$, and half the eigenvector $\Psi$ solutions are symmetric while the other half are antisymmetric. Are you familiar with experimental results whether helium atoms are observed to have a symmetric 2-electron wavefunction (boson) or antisymmetric 2-electron wavefunction (fermion), or whether it depends?

@James The coordinate-dependent factor in total $\Psi$ can be both symmetric or antisymmetric, depending on the spin factor (which depends on $m$'s). In the singlet state, the spin factor is antisymmetric, so the coordinate factor is symmetric. In triplet states, it is the other way around - the coordinate factor is antisymmetric. Only the total psi function (product of coordinate and spin function) is antisymmetric in all cases (total psi functions that are not, even if they are eigenfunctions of $\hat{H}_0$, are rejected).

@JánLalinský thank you! One final quick question please if you will, supposing we use momentum basis $\Psi(p_1, p_2)$ instead to solve for the 6 dimensional Schrodinger equation for helium, then 2 electrons residing at the same location in $\Psi(p_1, p_2)$ would mean a Cooper-pair like correlated movement between these 2 electrons, right? Doesn't Pauli exclusion principle apply in momentum basis too, so that 2 electrons having the same exact momentum is forbidden?

@james the Pauli ppl does not care about coordinates: only about exchange of particle labels.  Thus it applies equally well in momentum or position space.

@James the momentum-dependent factor can by symmetric (thus two electrons with same momentum are possible), if the spin factor is antisymmetric.

@JánLalinský In other question about possible states of 2-electron wavefunction, Chiral Anomaly wrote "A two-fermion state must be antisymmetric with respect to the exchange of all of their attributes, not just spin. If the state is symmetric with respect to the exchange of their spins, then it is antisymmetric with respect to the exchange of their other attributes" Does this mean that, suppose we don't theorize and simply measure a helium atom repeatedly, then sometimes we will measure antisymmetric $\Psi$, and other times symmetric $\Psi$, or will we see exclusively antisymmetric $\Psi$?

@James total $\Psi$ of electrons in helium atom is believed to be always anti-symmetric. The coordinate factor in it may be symmetric or anti-symmetric, depending on the actual state. In experiments, we see both kind of states - singlets and triplets.
